# Unexplained gap/padding to the left, between Toolbar, and LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, imageview, android-linearlayout

I have the following structure in the layout file of my Android studio project, and I see unexplained left padding between the parent element (Toolbar) and it's immediate child element (LinearLayout).

**Layout Text**

```
<Toolbar
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="600dp"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="#313B45"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/headerimage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</Toolbar>
```

How can I remove this gap and have the child LinearLayout align fully with the parent Toolbar?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Add these lines to your toolbar layout :
 For API<=21 toolbar :

```
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```

For API 21>= toolbar :

```
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```

The left inset is caused by Toolbar's contentInsetStart which by default is 16dp.

Here's the full code :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="600dp"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:background="#313B45"
android:weightSum="1"
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/headerimage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try including this in your build.gradle :                                                 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'

Comment: Thank you. I had added the app: prefix when i was using API 21. Using android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar always gives me runtimeerror in terms of inflating the toolbar.
Thanks for the answer !

Comment: you are a life saver!

Comment: is it possible if imageView (w,h: wrap_content) is inside Toolbar to align it with the toolbar top? I was trying everything but couldn't make it.. My goal is to have something like bookmark ribbon image"hanging" from the top of the Toolbar, bet there is always some padding that I can not eliminate

Answer (score 1):

The above answer helped solve only a part, add these lines and it should work fine

```
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/primaryColor"
        android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp" />
```

notice that **android:contentInsetLeft** and **app:contentInsetLeft** are 2 separate things and **both of them are needed**