# Android Toolbar Menu Item taking spaces . Don't Set Duplicate

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

My menu item are taking spaces. I know default padding is 56 dp but I don't know how to remove this. I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131954/is-there-a-way-to-reduce-the-spacing-between-the-action-item-icons-on-action-bar) but won't work for me.
I am using toolbar not action bar.

my toolbar is

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I am getting the output like below image ..how to remove spaces between menu item

[image]. ..

Comment: Try adding: 
android:padding="0dp"
android:layout_margin="0dp" 
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"

Comment: @MatthewHooker not working. i tried before

Comment: What API version are you using?

Comment: minSdkVersion 19,   targetSdkVersion 24,  buildToolsVersion "24.0.3", compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29447043/unexplained-gap-padding-to-the-left-between-toolbar-and-linearlayout

Comment: Try adding, either app:contentInsetLeft="0dp" app:contentInsetRight="0dp" app:contentInsetStart="0dp" or android:contentInsetLeft="0dp" android:contentInsetRight="0dp" android:contentInsetStart="0dp" not both.

Comment: nothing works for me ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132052/discussion-between-matthew-hooker-and-abhishek-singh).

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line to your Activity's theme

`<item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/OptionMenuStyle</item>`

and create new style in style resources

```
<style name="OptionMenuStyle" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:minWidth">20dip</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dip</item>
</style>
```

The problem with setting only 0dp padding is - option menu item has default minimum width, so setting 0dp padding doesn't change anything.

result before applying this style is as below.

[image]

result after applying above style

[image]

Cheers!!!